# /civicrm-stable/5.17.5/civicrm-5.17.5-l10n.tar.gz does not download

Tags: localisation, core

I am trying to download version 5.17.5 via SourceForge.

civicrm-5.17.5-drupal.tar.gz downloads, but /civicrm-stable/5.17.5/civicrm-5.17.5-l10n.tar.gz does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get it from https://civicrm.org/download that seems to work OK

Comment: Good idea ! Thank you.